# Can't change clock frequency (android)

Tags: shell

I try to change clock frequency to lower frequency (android), but although I get no error, it keeps using the other frequency.
                                                             <
    root@w812a_kk:/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq # ls
    affected_cpus
    cpuinfo_cur_freq
    cpuinfo_max_freq
    cpuinfo_min_freq
    cpuinfo_transition_latency
    related_cpus
    scaling_available_governors
    scaling_cur_freq
    scaling_driver
    scaling_governor
    scaling_max_freq
    scaling_min_freq
    scaling_setspeed
    stats

```
root@w812a_kk:/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq # cat cpuinfo_min_freq 
598000
root@w812a_kk:/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq # cat cpuinfo_max_freq
1001000
root@w812a_kk:/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq # echo "userspace" > scaling_governor
root@w812a_kk:/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq # echo 598000 > scaling_setspeed

root@w812a_kk:/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq # cat scaling_cur_freq
1001000
```

Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about Android, not about a Unix system. Android is a distinct operating system that uses the Linux kernel as a kernel, it is not a Linux system. You can ask Android questions on [android.se].

Comment: What device and custom kernel? You typically can't change the clocking or scaling of a stock kernel. Have you tried using Kernel Aduitor?

Comment: It does work on other devices.

Comment: Kernel Aduitor only shows status, can't change frequency with it